# How to reference self in a named scope? -- Rails 3.1 beginner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How do I reference self in the following?

`scope :children, where("parent_id = ?", self.id)`

self doesn't seem to work in this context

Comment: Scopes are just syntactic sugar to create class methods. So self in this context is the class itself and not an instance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Normally scopes are chained off the class, like this:

```
Foo.recent_entries.posts # Or whatever.
```

You'd need a lambda scope to get the same behavior:

```
scope :children_of, lambda { |o| where("parent_id=?", o.id }
```

I'm assuming you're trying to get a specific instance's children:

```
parent.children
```

This would be an instance method, but: this looks like a basic [self-referencing association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins), too, rather than something needing a scope.

*If you're making a tree there are gems for that, e.g., [closure-tree](https://github.com/ClosureTree/closure_tree), [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry), and others.*